# installing scipy in python2.6

Tags: python, scipy

when I am installing scipy0.14.0 in redhat6.1
then the following error throws. I have already installed lapack and blas. How can I resolve that.

```
compile options: '-DNO_ATLAS_INFO=1 -I/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c'
gcc: scipy/interpolate/_ppoly.c
In file included from /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1761,
                 from /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                 from /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from scipy/interpolate/_ppoly.c:314:
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION"
scipy/interpolate/_ppoly.c: In function â__pyx_f_5scipy_11interpolate_6_ppoly_croots_poly1â:
scipy/interpolate/_ppoly.c:11307: warning: implicit declaration of function âdgeev_â
scipy/interpolate/_ppoly.c: At top level:
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1629: warning: â_import_arrayâ defined but not used
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h:241: warning: â_import_umathâ defined but not used
/usr/bin/gfortran -Wall -Wall -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/scipy/interpolate/_ppoly.o -L/usr/src/lapack-3.5.0/ -L/usr/src/BLAS -L/usr/lib64 -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6 -llapack -lfblas -lpython2.6 -lgfortran -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/scipy/interpolate/_ppoly.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/src/lapack-3.5.0//liblapack.a(dgeev.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/src/lapack-3.5.0//liblapack.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/src/lapack-3.5.0//liblapack.a(dgeev.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/src/lapack-3.5.0//liblapack.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Command "/usr/bin/gfortran -Wall -Wall -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/scipy/interpolate/_ppoly.o -L/usr/src/lapack-3.5.0/ -L/usr/src/BLAS -L/usr/lib64 -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6 -llapack -lfblas -lpython2.6 -lgfortran -o build/lib.linux-x86_642.6/scipy/interpolate/_ppoly.so" failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Please post the whole output, there is probably more information before this last part.

Comment: Did you try recompiling with fPIC?

Comment: The whole o/p is very large.. I have posted here where it strucked...

Comment: Have you got installed Fortran 64 bit, the BLAS libraries (including the development headers), etc?

Comment: yah.. I have installed blas lib.. fortran..lapack lib

Comment: `/usr/src/lapack-3.5.0//liblapack.a: could not read symbols: Bad value` suggests that you need to uninstall and reinstall lapack, (including the dev files), *for the 64 bit version*.